# Foreach insert Laravel 5 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to insert records using a `foreach` loop.

```
$test = array(123, 231, 321, 543);

foreach($test as $key) {
    $data = array('name' => 'test_name', test' => $test[$key], 'property' => 'test_property');
    Test_table::insert($data);    
}
```

Using a `foreach` gives an error `Undefined offset: 123`.

Inserting this way works though:

```
 $data = array(
    array('name' => 'test_name', test' => 123, 'property' => 'test_property'), 
    array('name' => 'test_name', test' => 231, 'property' => 'test_property'), 
    array('name' => 'test_name', test' => 321, 'property' => 'test_property'), 
    array('name' => 'test_name', test' => 543, 'property' => 'test_property'),
  );
 Test_table::insert($data);
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$test = array(123, 231, 321, 543);
foreach($test as $key) {
    $data = array('name' => 'test_name', 'test' => $key, 'property' => 'test_property');
    Test_table::insert($data);    
}
```

This should work. You don't need to access `$test` by index since you already have the value in `$key` which is in fact a value from the array.

Comment: It takes time when array is too large,

Answer (score 0):

try following Code :

```
$test = array(123, 231, 321, 543);
foreach($test as $key) {

$createtesttable=Test_table::create(['name' => 'test_name', 'test' => $key, 'property' => 'test_property']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Eloquent::insert()`. You can also insert dynamically, I will discuss in below.

```
 $test = array(123, 231, 321, 543);
 foreach($test as $value) {
   $data = array(
      'name' => 'test_name', 
      'test' => $value, 
      'property' => 'test_property'
      );
   Test_table::insert($data);    
 }
```

`Eloquent::insert()` is the proper solution but it wont update the timestamps, so you can do something like below,

```
 $json_array=array_map(function ($a) { 
    return array_merge($a,
     [
      'created_at'=>Carbon::now(),
      'updated_at'=> Carbon::now()
     ]); 
 }, $json_array); 

 Model::insert($json_array);
```